# Un-paired t-test using data within one column

Tags: r, reshape, spread, t-test

I want to do an unpaired t-test to examine if **values** differ **between sites** in each **type** category.

So my question is, **within types** (AB or CD), do **values** (valueA or valueB) differ **between sites** (A or B)?

Here is an example of my data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  "site" = c("A","B","B","A","A","B","B","A"), 
  "type" = c("AB","CD"), 
  "valueA" = c(13,-10,-5,18,-14,12,-17,19), 
  "valueB" = c(-3,20,15,-16,12,15,-11,14)
)
dat

site type valueA valueB
A   AB     13     -3
B   CD    -10     20
B   AB     -5     15
A   CD     18    -16
A   AB    -14     12
B   CD     12     15
B   AB    -17    -11
A   CD     19     14
```

I am trying to do four **unpaired** t-tests to examine:

1. If valueA Type AB, differs between site A vs. site B
2. If valueB Type AB, differs between site A vs. site B
3. If valueA Type CD, differs between site A vs. site B
4. If valueB Type CD, differs between site A vs. site B

In order to run the unpaired t-test, I believe I need to re-arrange my data so that type AB and type CB and site A and site B are each a column (instead of being within the type or site column).

EDIT:

Using the suggested code in the comments:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(site, type) %>% 
  summarise(pval = t.test(valueA, valueB)$p.value)
```

The output is this:

```
site  type   pval
A     AB    0.784
A     CD    0.417
B     AB    0.492
B     CD    0.365
```

To my understanding, this p-value here is giving me the difference between valueA and valueB.

I am looking for, for example:
The difference between site A and site B of valueA in type CD.

So if I am thinking correctly, the output of the t-test should have a column for type, value A and value B. Then the p-values are for the differences between sites.

Similar to this:

```
type  valueA  valueB
AB     0.365   0.784
CD     0.492   0.417
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you're asking for. See if this works for you:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(valueA, valueB), names_to = "name", values_to = "val") %>%
  split(.$site) %>%
  map(., ~rename(.x, !!sym(paste0(.x$site[[1]], "val")) := val) %>%
        select(-site)) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = c("type", "name")) %>%
  group_by(type, name) %>%
  summarise(p.val = t.test(Aval, Bval)$p.value) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = type, names_from = name, values_from = p.val)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Groups:   type [2]
#>   type  valueA valueB
#>   <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 AB    0.284   0.785
#> 2 CD    0.0703  0.121
```

Here we go from wide to long, split the dataframe by site. Rename the values of interest to include the site, re-join the dataframe, and then run a grouped t.test by type and and site.

Answer (score 2):

We can do a `group_by` 'site', 'type' and apply the `t.test`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- dat %>% 
         group_by(site, type) %>% 
         summarise(pval = t.test(valueA, valueB)$p.value)
```

By default, `paired = FALSE` in `t.test`

The output above can be reshaped to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
out %>%
    ungroup %>%
    mutate(site = str_c('value', site)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = site, values_from = pval)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  type  valueA valueB
#  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 AB     0.784  0.492
#2 CD     0.417  0.365
```

---

If we want to compare the 'value' columns between 'AB' and 'CD'

```
dat %>% 
   group_by(site) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(starts_with('value')), 
          ~ t.test(.[type == 'AB'], .[type == 'CD'])$p.value)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  site  valueA valueB
#  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A      0.393  0.784
#2 B      0.464  0.439
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I have edited my question to ask another!

Comment: @jl748795 So, you want to just `reshape` it to 'wide' format

Comment: Thank you. The part of the code that says ** mutate(site = str_c('value', ... ** is only adding the word "value" in front of site A or site B in the column name. If I change the world value to 'vvv', it comes out as 'vvvA' and 'vvvB' in the column names. So it is not giving me columns for type, valueA and valueB, it is still giving me columns for type, site A and site B.